# VSCode - How to remove forward slash for folder inside folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to change workspace with forward slash to tree like the bottom one?
I was trying to find it on the settings on VSCode but no luck

**Forward Slash**

[image: Forward Slash]

**Tree**

[image]

Comment: Search for “Compact Folders” in settings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the setting "Compact Folders". Simply untick that option.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help. Just unchecked the option and it works like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The setting is called `Explorer: Compact Folders` and is available under Features/Explorer in settings or as

```
    "explorer.compactFolders": false
```

in the json settings file.